# Multi Level Menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a project and I need a multi level menu which will be dynamic, but for now I want it hardcoded (html / jquery / javascript / anything that will work).

The first level will be some icons which will be place horizontally. And when I click on any icon the second level will appear, which will have a sub menu (child elements) and the third level will have some children elements too.

The structure will be like this:

```
Icon1
 FirstMenu
   SecondMenu
     ThirdMenu
 FirstMenu
   SecondMenu
Icon2
 FirstMenu
   SecondMenu
     ThirdMenu
 FirstMenu
   SecondMenu
Icon3
 FirstMenu.
```

I was able to create a sublevel menu, but I can't figure it out how to put those icons in it, and on click to show me the children of it.

[image]

The menu should be like this. When I click on a icon, the right menu from the bottom should collapse. And when I click on HEAVY DUTY for example, a third level should appear.

Can you give me some hints or resources from where I can start ?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Provide some code you are working on.

Comment: This sounds like a 'homework' question with nothing to show what you have attempted already. Please edit the question and show people what you have tried/got already.

Comment: try the light weight and multilevel responsive menu -> github.com/hidaytrahman/hr-navigation-responsive-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. you can add fontawesome for the icons. Js Fiddle p9Lea8g4/7/